# Matrices that satisfy $AB = 0$ and $A^2 = B^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, matrices

I want to make a set of matrices that satisfies all the following:

1) $A^2 = B^2$, $C^2 =D^2$..... where $A,B,C,D...$ are matrices

2) $AB = 0$, $CD = 0$.....

3) All matrices in the set commute.

4) $AC \neq 0$, $AD \neq 0$, $BC \neq 0$, $BD \neq 0$.... so other than $AB$, $CD$ ... multiplication is always nonzero.

Also, is there any mathematical object that satisfies all of these?

Comment: Other than Kronecker prodcut way, are there other better ways to do this?

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: By better, I mean that the size of matrices being shorter.

Answer (score 3):

There's at least
$$ A=B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
C=D=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
I think this ought to generalize to $n$ pairs of $2^n\times 2^n$ matrices. Each matrix is a Kronecker product of $n$ matrices of which one is $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and the rest are $2\times 2$ identity matrices.

More generally if only you have an $A$ and $B$ with $A^2=B^2$, $AB=BA=0$, you can combine $n$ copies of this structure using Kronecker products. That automatically makes matrices from different pairs commute, and ensures that cross-level products are nonzero as long as the generators are.