# Matrices that satisfy $A^2,B^2,C^2$ and commute

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a set of matrices that satisfy all of the following constraints?

1) $A^2=0, B^2=0, C^2=0...$ where $A,B,C,D..$ are different matrices.

2) All of them commute.

Edit: 3) $AB \neq 0, AC \neq 0, BC \neq 0, ...$.

Comment: What about all entries 0 except an $a$ in the top right corner, $a$ ranging over the elements of your field.

Comment: edited. Forgot to mention 3).

Comment: My answer to [this earlier question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222040/matrices-that-satisfy-ab-0-and-a2-b2/222042#222042) works here too.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$E=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right), \ \ \ \ I=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right).$$

Then set

$$
A = E\otimes I\otimes I\otimes I,\\
B = I\otimes E\otimes I\otimes I,\\
C = I\otimes I\otimes E\otimes I,\\
D = I\otimes I\otimes I\otimes E.
$$

Where $\otimes$ is the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). These were constructed following the procedure outline by @HenningMakholm [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222040/matrices-that-satisfy-ab-0-and-a2-b2/222042#222042):

> More generally if only you have an $A$ and $B$ with $A^2=B^2$, $AB=BA=0$, you can combine $n$ copies of this structure using Kronecker products. That automatically makes matrices from different pairs commute, and ensures that cross-level products are nonzero as long as the generators are.